# python. как сохранить несколько значений в список через input

Tags: python, telegram-bot, list, список

Здравствуйте) Нужна помощь в сохранении нескольких переменных в список

```
list =['спать', 'Машина', 'Мотоцикл', 'Еще что-нибудь', 'тд']
num  =  input('Введите слово:')
list.append(num)
for i in list:
    print(i)
```

При перезапуске программы стирается предыдущий ввод. И все заново. Как сделать, чтобы  input вводил бы данные сколько угодно раз и дополнял список?)

Comment: Хранить переменную в файле

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете сохранять переменную в файл и загружать ее из него с помощью встроенного модуля `pickle`:

```py
import pickle
import os

storage_filename = "storage.pickle"

list = ['спать', 'Машина', 'Мотоцикл', 'Еще что-нибудь', 'тд']

if not os.path.exists(storage_filename): # Если файла не существует
    with open(storage_filename, "wb") as f: # То создаем его
        pickle.dump(list, f) # Сохрняя в него наш список
else: # Если же существует
    with open(storage_filename, "rb") as f:
        list = pickle.load(f) # То загружаем из него список

num = input('Введите слово:')
list.append(num)
for i in list:
    print(i)

with open(storage_filename, "wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(list, f) # Сохраняем измененный список в файл
```